# Python Scrapy Login to website then scrape data, Can't add new url to scrapte

Tags: python, authentication, request, scrapy

I want to scrape some data from my own website,I have already finish login

```
    def start_requests(self):
    return [Request("http://localhost:8080/website/admin.php?s=/Public/login.html",
                    cookies={'PHPSESSID': '4titclg3ihgdprp5308vnp4gj6',
                             'onethink_admin___forward__': '%2Fwebsite%2Fadmin.php%3Fs%3D%2FMenu%2Findex%2Fpid%2F16.html'},
                    callback=self.post_login)]
```

but when I scrape data from the other pages, I try to use: yield scrapy.Request(url,callback) to add a new request to downloader,the method wasn't started

```
    def post_login(self, response):
    if response.url != "http://localhost:8080/website/admin.php?s=/Public/login.html":
        self.go_main(response)
    else:
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                              method='POST',
                                              headers=self.headers,
                                              formdata={
                                                  'username': 'admin',
                                                  'password': '123456'
                                              },
                                              callback=self.after_login,
                                              dont_filter=True
                                              )]
    def after_login(self, response):
    log.info(response.body)
    json_array = json.loads(str(response.body, encoding="utf-8"))
    if json_array['status'] == 1:
        create_excel_file()
        self.make_url_to_join(response)
    else:
        log.info("error code:" + str(json_array['status']))

    def go_main(self, response):
    self.make_url_to_join(response)

def make_url_to_join(self, response):
    for con in self.config:
        register_url = "http://localhost:8080/website/admin.php?s=/Platform/promote_statistics&timestart=" + str(
            yesterday) + "&timeend=" + str(yesterday) + "&promote_id=" + con['id']
        spend_url = "http://localhost:8080/website/admin.php?s=/Platform/promotepay_statistics&timestart=" + str(
            yesterday) + "&timeend=" + str(yesterday) + "&promote_id=" + con['id']
        log.debug(register_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(register_url, callback=self.parse_register_item)
        yield scrapy.Request(spend_url, callback=self.parse_spend_item)

def parse_register_item(self, response):
    log.info("register_data_url：" + response.url)

def parse_spend_item(self, response):
    log.info("spend_data_url：" + response.url)
```

every time I scrape data,the make_url_to_join can't run and I can't add new request to spider,How can I do? please help me out,thanks

Comment: Could you provide more specific information: do you get an error? If so, please provide it

Comment: sorry,the log at first answer,but unuseful,the make_url_to_join never start

Comment: You can edit your question (button edit under tags) instead of putting it in an answer